# One object is inside of one array and how can I take that object's value in flutter when one button pressed

Tags: flutter, function, dart

How to use answers arrays objects values inside of pressAnswer function and Text()

```dart
  List<Object> answers = [
    {
      'a': 'Red',
      'b': 'Blue',
      'c': 'Yellow',
      'd': 'Black',
    },
  ];

ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()=>pressAnswer(), child: Text(),)
```

Comment: can you include your widget ?

Answer (score 0):

On your widget class, you can define function like

```dart
final Function({required String option,required String answer}) pressAnswer;
```

Now to use it, you can do

```dart
ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()=>pressAnswer(option: "YourPressedOption",answer:"YourPressedAns" ), child: Text(),)
```

Also you can pass as map, or just a single string.